# Stub the behavior of a readOnly property

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks, stub

```
public interface ICell
        {
            int Value{get;}

            void IncrementValue();
        }
```

I want to create a stub for this interface in RhinoMocks.
I have a read only property and i want to increment his value every time i call the IncrementValue() method. Is this possible? I don't want to create a class new for this stub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have similar proposal to Jay, just shorter. Not sure if this have some drawbacks so.

```
   int count = 0;

    var mock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ICell>();
    mock.Stub(p => p.Value).WhenCalled(a => a.ReturnValue = count).Return(42);
    mock.Stub(p => p.IncrementValue()).WhenCalled(a => {
        count = (int)count+1; 
    });
```

Return(42) is put there to say "Value returns something, don't throw" and WhenCalled(a => a.ReturnValue = count) overrides that return vale 42 with current value of the count.

Answer (score 0):

You can give rhino mocks a lambda to run when a function get's called. This lambda can then increment a counter.  You can find an example [here](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2010/06/30/change-return-value-of-a-mock-based-on-parameters-in-rhino-mocks/)

Comment: i guess martin's problem is what to increment... the interface only has a get-property, no set

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this too:

```
cell.Stub(c => c.Value).WhenCalled(m => m.ReturnValue = cell.GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn(c => c.IncrementValue()).Count).Return(0);
```

Before your help i was confused with the behavior of WhenCalled method... but i think your approach is better than this one